# bold tag causes line to jump out of the div

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for a paragraph with a grid class and a flex-item.  The first line is bold but the bold tag causes the line to jump to the left of the center_text_grid.

```css
.center_text_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 5 / 12;
  grid-row: 20 / 20;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.mktg_text {
  font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  color: rgb(175, 222, 162);
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text"><b>Thanks for your interest in our product.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;We are excited to offer it, along with all accessories, six months ahead of schedule.&nbsp;&nbsp;The interest has been exceptional, and we appreciate all of the comments we received during its
  development.&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br></div>
```

Why does the bold tag cause the line to jump out of the div?

Comment: I see its working fine, what do you mean "jump out of the div"?

Comment: Is the CSS in your initial question the entirety of the CSS for the page?  Taking your question and the comment above together, it sounds like there may be a rule somewhere else in your CSS that is targeting all <b> tags

Comment: The first line shows stacked to the left.  I can't reproduce it here.  This may be because this area is part of a larger grid - the page is inserted into a div within  another page using javascript.  @bluemoon6790, that may be but I don't think so.  I will look for that.  Based on the comments here, I think it's related to other page elements too detailed to post, especially because others have no problem with it.